# Problem 2.2 Real Analysis Folland

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to solve this problem:

If $f,g:X\to \overline{\mathbb R}$ are measurable and $c$ is any extended real value the function $$h(x)=\begin{cases}c& \text{if}\  f(x)+g(x)\ \text{is undefined}\\ f(x)+g(x)& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ is measurable.

Comment: It needs a little more finesse: Note that $h^{-1} (\{c\})$ includes the points where $f+g$ are undefined. Umberto's answer provides a nice approach.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for your comment. Umberto's answer is great. Could you please correct my answer?

Comment: It is messy to try and prove it that way, since $Y$ above includes points where $f+g$ is undefined (and hence the second equality in the second last paragraph is incorrect). So using that approach involves more modifications than just correcting...

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on how much of the theory you are allowed to use. Sum and products of measurable functions are measurable, level sets of measurable functions are measurable sets, and $\chi_E$ is a measurable function if and only if $E$ is a measurable set.

Note that $f(x) + g(x)$ is undefined if and only if $$x \in (\{f = \infty\} \cap \{g = -\infty\} ) \cup ( \{f = -\infty\} \cap \{g = \infty\}).$$
Denote this set by $B$ (for bad) and its complement $G$ (for good).  Then $f \chi_G + g \chi_G$ is well-defined so that $$h = c \chi_B + f \chi_G + g \chi_G$$
is measurable, even if $c = \pm \infty$.

Comment: Minor nit: $f\chi_G + g\chi_G$ is defined everywhere (which is what matters) but not necessarily finite-valued: $G$ includes any points where $f(x) = g(x) = \infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: Good eye. Thanks.